# Triple Boot Ubuntu using Clover (Windows 10, MacOS & Ubuntu)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, windows, mac

My PC currently has Windows 10 and Mac installed on separate hard drives with Clover bootloader managing the boot process. I've recently purchased a third hard drive to install Ubuntu onto it; however, I'm unsure what the best way is to proceed considering tutorials and threads for dual boot systems are far more common than triple boot systems with my configuration.

**How should I install Ubuntu onto my third hard drive while ensuring I can pick between all three operating systems on Clover during the boot process?**

I was considering unplugging all my other drives (Windows and Mac) and doing a "standard" install of Ubuntu, which would not affect my other drives; however, given my elementary knowledge of bootloaders etc. I wasn't sure if Clover would be able to detect the drive after I reconnected the other two drives once installation of Ubuntu was complete. Note I'm flexible on using Clover to boot if there's a superior and easier method.

P.S. I've already created a bootable USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone has the same requirements as me and wants to triple boot, watch [this fantastic video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VrkhWZ8-zvM&index=2&t=27s&list=PLc53GCDreoGdY-iRCe_e3ShbeEFeH_gAa)

Here is a short summary of the steps:

1. Install MacOS and Windows 10 in UEFI mode (seek help elsewhere with this if needed)
2. Download [Ubuntu desktop](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
3. Use Rufus to write the iso to a USB key

   - Select the correct USB device if more than one is plugged in
   - Set partition scheme to GPT (as we are using UEFI)
   - Choose Create a bootable disk using iso and select the iso you downloaded
4. When done, reboot with the USB key plugged in. If your system has an nvidia graphics card you may have problems, If so, move the cursor to **Install Ubuntu** and press <kbd>E</kbd> to enter the GRUB editor. Go to the line beginning `linux` and press <kbd>N</kbd> or move the cursor to go to the end of the line. Here add the parameter `nouveau.modeset=0` and press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

   If you prefer, you can disconnect the drives Windows and MacOS are installed on to be totally sure you are not going to overwrite them.
5. Go through the installation process:

   - Connect to the internet if possible
   - Select the option to install 3rd party drivers
   - If you have multiple disk drives and want to install Ubuntu on an empty drive, select **Erase the disk and install Ubuntu**. In the dialog, be very sure to select the correct drive. An empty drive will have no partitions, but the installer will show partitions on Windows and MacOS drives. You can also disconnect your Windows and MacOS drives if you want to.
   - Confirm write changes to disk, set up you user account, wait for the installation to finish, remove the USB key, and reboot
6. Enter the BIOS/UEFI settings and use trial and error to determine which of the boot options is Clover (the option may not have a helpful name)

   Inside Clover, you won't see any Linux partitions, so boot into MacOS to fix that
7. Configure Clover to recognise Linux partitions

   - Go to the Clover Configurator (you may need to install it)
   - Select <kbd>Mount EFI partition</kbd> and, by trial and error, find the EFI partition and click the import button
   - Click on **config.plist**
   - In the left sidebar, click **GUI**
   - In the **Scan** section check the box for **Linux**
8. Reboot and you should see Linux in Clover.
9. For nvidia cards

   - Access the GRUB menu after selecting Linux in Clover and press <kbd>E</kbd> to enter the GRUB editor. Move the cursor to the line beginning `linux` and replace `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
   - Go to **Software & Updates > Other Software > Additional Drivers** and choose *use Nvidia binary driver*